# Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?

Tags: c#, string, escaping, literals, verbatim-string

In a verbatim string literal (@"foo") in C#, backslashes aren't treated as escapes, so doing \" to get a double quote doesn't work. Is there any way to get a double quote in a verbatim string literal?

This understandably doesn't work:

```
string foo = @"this \"word\" is escaped";
```

Comment: The most comprehensive answer is *[rfonn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal/1928943#1928943)* (e.g., for folks ending up here from a search engine, e.g. searching for "escape quotes C#")

Answer (score 927, accepted):

Use a duplicated double quote.

```
@"this ""word"" is escaped";
```

outputs:

```
this "word" is escaped
```

Comment: I'm trying to use @Html.Raw() and the quadruple quote breaks my string

Comment: Can you use it without the string literal? It seems like Html.Raw() would take care of ensuring it's a string for you...

Comment: It's also possible to use it in combination with string interpolation: `$@"this ""{wordVar}"" is escaped";`.

Comment: Perhaps be explicit about whether this is the only way or not? What about later developments, like C# 6? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 119):

Use double quotation marks.

```
string foo = @"this ""word"" is escaped";
```

Answer (score 96):

This should help clear up any questions you may have: [C# literals](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Strings.aspx)

Here is a table from the linked content:

> | Regular literal | Verbatim literal | Resulting string |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `"Hello"` | `@"Hello"` | `Hello` |
> | `"Backslash: \\"` | `@"Backslash: \"` | `Backslash: \` |
> | `"Quote: \""` | `@"Quote: """` | `Quote: "` |
> | `"CRLF:\r\nPost CRLF"` | `@"CRLF: Post CRLF"` | `CRLF: Post CRLF` |

Comment: What about escaping of `{` and `}`?

Comment: @PeterMortensen - Neither of those syntaxes require any escape for `{` or `}`. Are you thinking of `interpolated string` syntax `$`?

Comment: A lot was added to C# since its first inception. Do we have a way define string literals with lots of double quotes without having to escape them nowadays? (i.e. by using another string delimiter like we can use in sed or perl?)

Comment: [user1234567's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal/66688029#66688029) covers string brace escape sequences, {{ and }}.

Answer (score 96):

For adding some more information, your example will work without the `@` symbol (it prevents escaping with \), this way:

```
string foo = "this \"word\" is escaped!";
```

It will work both ways but I prefer the double-quote style for it to be easier working, for example, with filenames (with lots of \ in the string).

Answer (score 8):

Update: With C# 11 Preview feature - Raw String Literals

```
string foo1 = """
   this "word" is escaped
   """;

string foo2 = """this "word" is escaped""";
```

---

History:

There is a proposal open in GitHub for the C# language about having better support for raw string literals. One valid answer, is to encourage the C# team to add a new feature to the language (such as triple quote - like Python).

see https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/89#discussioncomment-257343

Comment: This got upgraded to a real proposal https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/4304, and now it's in the C#11 Preview! see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-11#raw-string-literals

Comment: Exactly what I need in LINQPad (so dotnet7 preview it is...)

Answer (score 2):

As [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) says:

> Simple escape sequences ... are interpreted literally. Only a quote escape sequence (`""`) is not interpreted literally; it produces one double quotation mark. Additionally, in case of a verbatim interpolated string brace escape sequences (`{{` and `}}`) are not interpreted literally; they produce single brace characters.

Comment: NOTE: **only** `interpolated string` syntax `$"..."` requires escaping of `{` and `}`. Regular strings `"..."`  and verbatim strings `@"..."` do not require those to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Since C#11 you can use [raw strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/raw-string), which are delimited by three double quotes.

They can be either single or multiline:

```py
var singleLine = """Anything, including " is supported here without escaping""";
var multiLine = """
    Any blank after the opening quotes in previous line is discarded.
    This is WYSIWYG, including "quotes" and new lines.
        This line is indented by 4 characters, not 8, because
    the number of characters before the closing quotes
    of the next line are removed from each line.
    """;
```

The multiline version keeps the new lines and indenting, but interestingly it discards the characters before the indentation of the closing """ as explained above. And, as expected, the first line is the one below the opening, and the last is the one before the closing quotes.

And you can also use `@"""` for interpolation, like

```py
var @"""
    The value of "{property}" is:
    {value}
    """;
```

*NOTE: I formatted the code as python in this answer, because the C# formatter is not aware of this yet, and python formatter keeps this more readable*