# How to use double quotes in a string when using the @ symbol?

Tags: c#, .net, string, escaping, literals

I need to use double quotes in a string that uses the @ symbol. Using double quotes is breaking the string. I tried escaping with \, but that doesn't work. Ideas?

[image]

Comment: Same as [
In C#, can I escape a double quote in a literal string?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You double the quotes inside a verbatim string to get a quote character.

This makes your given sample:

```
(@"PREFIX rdfs: <" + rdfs + @">
      SELECT ?s ?p ?o
        WHERE { ?s ?p rdfs:Literal }
              {?s rdfs:label ""date""}");
```

Answer (score 25):

I believe this should work:

```
string myString = @"Here is my ""quoted"" text.";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if you want to write into a file :

```
string myString = @"Here is my ""quoted""text.";
myString.Replace(@"""",@"&quot;");
```