# How to use a string with quotation marks inside it?

Tags: c#, string, double-quotes

I have the following string, which I want to execute as a process:

`Rundll32 Printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /q /m "SHARP MX-5500N PS" /h "Windows NT x86" /v 3 /f sn0hwenu.inf`

However, given the presence of quotation marks, I can't insert this string in C# to make it compile, keeping all of the original structure. How should I fix this? It's a little tricky as there are quotation marks within the string.

Comment: Yup, this is called 'escaping' and usually you prefix the character in question with a backslash (\).

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, can I escape a double quote in a literal string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Answer (score 41):

```
string whatever = "Rundll32 Printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /q /m \"SHARP MX-5500N PS\" /h \"Windows NT x86\" /v 3 /f sn0hwenu.inf";
```

or

```
string whatever = @"Rundll32 Printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /q /m ""SHARP MX-5500N PS"" /h ""Windows NT x86"" /v 3 /f sn0hwenu.inf";
```

Answer (score 20):

You can put @ in front of the string definition and put two `"`:

```
string myString = @"Rundll32 Printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /q /m ""SHARP MX-5500N PS"" /h ""Windows NT x86"" /v 3 /f sn0hwenu.inf"
```

You can read more about escaping characters in strings in this article:

http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/strings.html

Answer (score 5):

you have to *escape* the quotation marks using `\`. to have a string that says: `Hello "World"` you should write `"Hello\"World\""`

Answer (score 4):

```
string s = "Rundll32 Printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ia /K /q /m \"SHARP MX-5500N PS\" /h \"Windows NT x86\" /v 3 /f sn0hwenu.inf";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also always use Convert.ToChar(34), 34 being the ASCII of ".

for eg:

```
gitInfo.Arguments = @"commit * " + "-m" + Convert.ToChar(34) + messBox.Text + Convert.ToChar(34);
```

equals:

```
commit * -m "messBox.Text";
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with C# 11, it is possible to use three quotes (""") at the beginning and end of a string, instead of just one as usual:

```
string s = """{ "Id": 1, "Name": "Alex" }""";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put in a backslash `\` before the quotation marks as needed:

```
string yourString = "This is where you put \"your\" string";
```

The string now contains: `This is where you put "your" string`