# How do I escape quotes in a string variable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this: 
And i want to put it in this:

```
 string firstTag = "";
```

So in the end i will get: string firstTag = "";
And if i will use a breakpoint on firstTag i will see only:

This is what i have tried:

```
public static void test(string filename)
        {
            filename = @"c:\temp\scoopstest\scooptest.html";

            int f = 0;
            int startPos = 0;
            string firstTag = "<font color="898A8E">";
```

But i'm getting error on: 898A8E">"

Comment: also see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you get that error. You have to escape the quotes:

```
"<font color=\"898A8E\">"
             ^       ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm answering the question correctly, but

```
string firstTag = "<font color="898A8E">";
```

looks problematic if you don't [escape the quotation marks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540701/how-to-use-a-string-with-quotation-marks-inside-it):

```
string firstTag = "<font color=\"898A8E\">";
```