# How to include quotes in quotes c#

Tags: c#, quotes

My code here:

```
String text = "" + label1.Text + ""; //label1 is: C:\myfiles\download
textBox1.Text = text;
```

I would textbox shown after I built: (has quotes)

```
"C:\myfiles\download"
```

Please help me.

Thank you very much.
Sorry my English is bad.

Comment: `String text = "\"" + label1.Text + "\"";`?

Answer (score 2):

In order to *avoid* such errors, use *formatting*:

```
  textBox1.Text = String.Format("\"{0}\"", label1.Text);
```

and let compiler ensure that the provided string `"\"{0}\""` is free from typos.

Answer (score 1):

This?

```
String text = "\"" + label1.Text + "\""; //label1 is: C:\myfiles\download
```

This escapes the quotes meaning: the character after the `\` has no special meaning any more and is a usual character.

Or even easier using verbatim-string:

```
String text = @"""" + label1.Text + @""""; //label1 is: C:\myfiles\download
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solving your problem

You need to use backslashes. The second occurence of <kbd>"</kbd> will escape the string declaration. Backslashes will prevent this.

```
String text = "\"" + label1.Text + "\""; 
textBox1.Text = text;
```

### Now, a little refactoring

You don't need to declare a variable, except you use this value again. Futhermore, you can use `string.Format()`. For more information about this method, watch the link in the references section.

```
textBox1.Text = string.Format("\"{0}\"", label1.Text);
```

### Some references

- This Stackoverflow-question focuses on the same problem:
  [How to use a string with quotation marks inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540701/how-to-use-a-string-with-quotation-marks-inside-it)
- Here a MSDN reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983682(v=vs.71).aspx
- [MSDN reference string.Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Using C# 6, you can very neatly do this using the following syntax:

```
textBox1.Text = $"\"{label1.Text}\"";
```

This is shorthand for `textBox1.Text = String.Format("\"{0}\"", label1.Text);` and, as with `String.Format`, the compiler will check the validity of the string for you.

Answer (score 0):

Double quotation mark represented by `\"` as an [escape sequence character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx) like;

```
String text = "\"" + label1.Text + \""";
```

Or you can double it with a [verbatim string literal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) as;

```
String text = @"""" + label1.Text + @"""";
```

Or you can use `string.Format` as;

```
String text = string.Format("\"{0}\"", label1.Text);
```