# SQL expressions as column name with Oracle 12c database

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

we have migrated our Oracle Database to 12c. I have a given table with column names DATE and HOUR (not possible to change). Before I used this statement with c#:

```
command.CommandText = @"SELECT ""DATE"", ""HOUR"" FROM Table";
```

This statement is not running with 12c:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

What do I have to change? Thanks

Comment: Are the column names all uppercase?

Comment: @Aleksej Yes they are

Comment: @Aleksej `DATE` is a keyword in Oracle and cannot be used as an identifier unless it is surrounded in double quotation marks.

Comment: @MT0 My bad, I did not see the (obvious) reason for the quotes...

Comment: It seems nothing was changed in this area in 12c. Maybe a driver issue?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz yes seemed to be a driver issue, thanks for that hint

Comment: @katz, great. was it solved?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz yes :)

Comment: @katz, Happy to hear. I have added an answer for documentation purposes, could you please fill in the details? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use double quotes (without the `\` escape character) to specify a keyword as an identifier for an object in the database:

```
SELECT "DATE", "HOUR" FROM Table;
```

*Note: If you are going to use double quotes around an identifier (which you have to do if you are using a keyword as a column name) then you are enforcing the use of a case-sensitive name for that column and you must always use the same case letters in the name every time you refer to it - see [my answer here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38328674/1509264).*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the Oracle SQL Developer this is working, but I need this for a query from c#. When I use only `"DATE"` it gives me an error because the string expects a `;` after the second `"`

Comment: @katz You appear to be doing it correctly in the sample code given in your question given the answers here: [How to use a string with quotation marks inside it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5540701/how-to-use-a-string-with-quotation-marks-inside-it)

Answer (score 0):

Driver issue

@katz - please fill in the details.
Thanks