# Turning a single quote into an escaped single quote within a string

Tags: c#, string, replace, escaping

It pains me to ask this, but, for some reason I have not been able to get this to work (it's late in the day, yes, that's my excuse).

Let's say I have this string:

```
s = "John's book."
```

Using the `replace` method from the object String, I want to turn it into this:

```
s = "John\'s book."
```

I would have expected this code to give me what I want:

```
s = s.Replace("'", "\\'")
```

But, that results in:

```
"John\\'s book."
```

Comment: what you're doing looks like it should work. Is that result from the debugger? I think VS will "help" by showing a '\\' instead of a '\'.

Comment: @SirPentor - Indeed.  I had it right, but, the debugger was showing me a different value.

Comment: This is in the top 2 for a search engine hit for "C# escape single quotes"... What is the canonical question for escaping string in C#? It definitely exists. Candidate: *[Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal/1928943#1928943)* (as an answer covers the most common cases and the external reference the rest).

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Do this so you don't have to think about it:

```
s = s.Replace("'", @"\'");
```

Comment: I had tried that previously, and that did not work either.  It results in: `John\\'s book.`

Comment: I think you may just be viewing it in the debugger/inspector which will show it escaped (twice) but if you do `Console.Write()` it should output correctly.

Comment: You're probably debugging and looking at the result by hovering over `s` in Visual Studio...  yes, that shows the escapes; coz that's the truth.  But if you output the string somewhere (a text box, or in the console) it'll come out with a single slash.

Comment: I guess I had it right all along.  Although I don't agree that what the debugger was showing is "the truth", because it's not what the value truly is.

Comment: Anyone care to modify this to explain why the literal works when the standards string notatiton does not?

Comment: @manuelhe; both `s.Replace("'", @"\'");` and `s.Replace("'", "\\'");` will give the same result -- the difference is in the debugger itself; it shows the string value as `"John\\'s book."` with an extra slash. But if you output this in Console or a file, you will see the real result `"John\'s book."`.

Comment: Is this supposed to work for http header values? I tried but it didn't.

Answer (score 9):

Just to show another possible solution if this is pertaining to [ASP.NET MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC) (ASP.NET MVC 5 or later):

```
var data= JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model.memberObj)))');
```

This allows you to escape *and* pass data to views as JavaScript.
The key part is:

```
HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode
```

Answer (score 4):

I have a quick-and-dirty function to escape text before using it in a MySQL insert clause. This might help:

```
    public static string MySqlEscape(Object usString)
    {
        if (usString is DBNull)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            string sample = Convert.ToString(usString);
            return Regex.Replace(sample, @"[\r\n\x00\x1a\\'""]", @"\$0");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I'm using C#, Sqlite, etc. What I get is a backslash in front of the single quote, which isn't how Sqlite escapes single quotes.

Comment: @sapbucket as noted, this is for mysql.  You could change it to insert the correct esc sequence.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest one would be

```
Server.HtmlEncode(varYourString);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to let you know in this case

```
string q = "John's book";
string s = s.Replace("'", "\\'");
string t = s.Replace("'", "\\\'");
```

s and t will display same thing;

https://dotnetfiddle.net/OwGyHW