# Use inline style in ASP.NET code file

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good Day.

I want to send an email from my code file in ASP.NET.
I want to apply styling to my html...How do I do it?

Here is the html part:

```
var Message = string.Format("<html><head></head><body><div style=""this does not work!!"">{0}<br/>{1}<br />{2}<br />{3}<br />{4}<br />{5}</body></html>", emaildetail.Name, emaildetail.Surname, emaildetail.CardProvider, emaildetail.CardType, emaildetail.CardNo, emaildetail.SuspendGuid); 

SendEmail("my email address", "Suspended Message", Message, true, null, true, 587);
```

I tried using double quotes, but it does not work.

How can I do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally in such circumstances it's much less work and more pretty (as much as that can be) to use single quotes *within* the double quotes of a literal string; of course you can *escape* the doubles with a backslash, or a prefixed `@`, but there's very little point, and more typing or confusion:

```
<html><head></head><body><div style='this will work!!'
```

However, another crux of your problem might exist even so, as clients may render styles at discretion.

Comment: OH so just single quotes will work just as good? So using single quotes won't make the styling be ignored in any way?

Comment: Nope, in fact, by the standards most clients go by, unquoted HTML probably still works in most of them. Single quotes will be fine, if a client is going to ignore a style property it's going to do it regardless.

Answer (score 2):

Either use a @ prefix:

```
@"Some text ""here""";
```

or use a backslash to escape the quotes:

```
"Some text \"here\"";
```

Comment: what does the 'some text' refer to?

Comment: whatever your text is.. in thsi case your html

Comment: Just stick a @ character in front like this: `string.Format(@"<html>...etc` and see if that works first

Comment: Both of these are the lesser way, IMO; this scenario is perfect for single quotes. the prefix and escaping just make the string more convoluted.

Comment: @GrantThomas I see this as a limitation in C# itself. This kind of task would be a lot nicer if C# supported string interpolation like [Nemerle](http://nemerle.org/wiki/index.php?title=Features#String_interpolation) or [Ruby](http://kconrails.com/2010/12/08/ruby-string-interpolation/)

Comment: @MattDavey How come? There are at least two ways that are _much_ cleaner than either of these.

Comment: @GrantThomas in Nemerle I would write `$"<html><head></head><body><div style='my-style'>$emaildetail.Name<br/>$emaildetail.Surname<br />...</body></html>"` No need for those nasty placeholders. Granted building up the HTML this way is horrible - far better to use a templating engine.

Answer (score 1):

```
var Message = string.Format(@"<html><head></head><body><div style=""this does not work!!"">{0}<br/>{1}<br />{2}<br />{3}<br />{4}<br />{5}</body></html>", emaildetail.Name, emaildetail.Surname, emaildetail.CardProvider, emaildetail.CardType, emaildetail.CardNo, emaildetail.SuspendGuid);
```

You need to escape your string using the @.

See this post

[Escape Double Quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string)

Answer (score -1):

use \ as an escape character before your quotes...

```
var Message = string.Format("<html><head></head><body><div style=\"\">")
```