# escaping characters

Tags: c#, javascript

How can I escape the Quotes so that this statement

```
string sScript =@"<script language='javascript'>function ShowDropDown(){var combo = $find("""+this.ClientID+""");combo.showDropDown(true);}</script>";
```

reads like this

```
function ShowDropDown() {
                var combo = $find("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_VendorTypeIdComboBox");
                combo.showDropDown(true);
            }
```

**EDIT- UPDATE**
I might of asked the question wrong because i keep getting different errors.  If I put the javascript directly on the page normally the function works.  When I inject the javascript this way it doesnt work

I am doing this in code behind

```
string sScript =@"<script language='javascript'> function ShowDropDown(){  var combo = $find("""+this.ClientID+@"""); combo.showDropDown(true); } </script>";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "autoopendropdown", sScript, false);

        OnClientFocus = "ShowDropDown()";
```

it gets generated this way

```
<script language='javascript'> function ShowDropDown(){  var combo = $find("ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_MainContent_VendorTypeIdComboBox"); combo.showDropDown(true); } </script>
```

but the variable ***combo*** is null and thats what the problem is. I cant figure out why when it is registered with code-behind it doesnt work and when write it normally on the page it does.

Comment: Life may be easier if you just use single quotes in JavaScript... Also you need to make sure there is no chance to get quotes in variables you are concatenating - you may need to add something like "escape all quotes in an argument" method...

Comment: Everyone is getting hung up on the C# quoting. It's valid. He's outputting javascript from C#.

Comment: yes, the question is "reads like this" which is ignored in most answers here.  @rein, your answer provides one way to do this.

Comment: The line breaks are a matter of format in the question so it was not all on one line. The question literally states "How can I escape the Quotes" and will fail at `+"""` with the error "; expected".

Comment: @TravisJ - I'm not sure where you're seeing that the error "; expected" is raised. From the updated question text this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: @rein - That was from the original question. The updated question will execute without error.

Comment: I am getting am error chrome and IE.  when inspect the page in Chrome combo is undefined.  When I build and run from VS2012 and target IE it crashes saying the same thing before the page even finishes building.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, can I escape a double quote in a literal string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string)

Comment: @ChampionChris - just to be clear you DO have a function in your script elsewhere literally named "$find"? and if you replace "language='javascript'" with "type='text/javascript'" it does not change the result? –

Answer (score 1):

Simple way: Add the same `@` at the beginning of the second string literal:

```
string sScript =@"<script language='javascript'>function ShowDropDown(){var combo = $find("""+this.ClientID+@""");combo.showDropDown(true);}</script>";
```

Better way: use string.Format

```
string sScript = string.Format(
@"<script language='javascript'>
    function ShowDropDown(){
        var combo = $find(""{0}"");combo.showDropDown(true);
    }
</script>",
    this.ClientID);
```

(Best way: separate concerns using unobtrusive javascript.)

Answer (score 1):

```
string sScript = "<script language='javascript'>\n" +
                 "function ShowDropDown() {\n" +
                 "    var combo = $find(""" + this.ClientID + """);\n" +
                 "    combo.showDropDown(true);\n" +
                 "}\n" +
                 "</script>";
```

Comment: yuck was my first thought here

Comment: It's not pretty but without a templating language you don't have much choice.

Comment: Yes, it works, but also see my answer using a string literal.  Gets the same result of the "format/looks like" requirement which is missing in lots of answers.  We shall let the OP determine which is best methinks. :)

Comment: @Mark: I'm torn between the two approaches (yours and mine). Mine's ugly and yours has the unfortunate side effect that it messes up the program indentation in the C# file, so it's hard to align statements before and after the string assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The escape for double quotes in C# (and most C family languages) is `\"`

Or you could just use single quotes since it's valid in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to concatenate `this.ClientID` with the rest of the script.

You can do this using the `String.Format` method like so:

```
string scriptFormat = @"<script language='javascript'>function ShowDropDown(){var combo = $find(""{0}"");combo.showDropDown(true);}</script>";
string sScript = String.Format(scriptFormat, this.ClientID);
```

Note that inside a verbatim string literal, `""` produces a single `"` character.

Answer (score 0):

You can escape them using the `\` character.

For a complete list of escape combinations, see section 2.4.4.4 Character literals of the C# [language specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: language is deprecated for script tags, use type

```
string sScript =@"
<script type='text/javascript'>
function ShowDropDown(){
                var combo = $find(""" + this.ClientID + @""");
                combo.showDropDown(true);
            }
</script>";
```