# Double quotes inside string HTML

Tags: c#, string

I want to store this:

```
<span class="icon phone">m</span>
```

in a string. How do I do this?

Tried: `@"<span class="+"icon phone"+">m</span>";`

Tried: `@"<span class="+@"icon phone"+">m</span>";`

Please help!

Comment: Use two double-quotes in a row:  `""`

Comment: You could also escape like this:  `"<span class=\"icon phone\">m</span>`"

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string ;)

Comment: Save it in a text file. Then from code, read the first line of that file (remember to trim the line ending!).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use single quotes, instead.

```
var html = "<span class='icon phone'>m</span>";
```

or double the quotes in a literal string

```
var html = @"<span class=""icon phone"">m</span>";
```

or escape the quote characters with the backslash character

```
var html = "<span class=\"icon phone\">m</span>";
```

Comment: Single quotes are valid in HTML4 (and 5? not sure), but not in XHTML... btw, you have an extra single quote at the end of your second code snippet

Comment: single quotes are valid in XHTML. fixed the typo, thx

Comment: My mistake; I was pretty sure they were forbidden in XML (thus in XHTML too), but apparently I was wrong about that...

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
new XElement("span", new XAttribute("class", "icon phone"), "m").ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also omit the @ and escape the double quote with a backslash `\`:

```
"<span class=\"icon phone\">m</span>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by typing " twice. It will appear once, inside a @-string.

So, in your case, to store:

```
<span class="icon phone">m</span>
```

Your string would be:

```
string s = @"<span class=""icon phone"">m</span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

To save a quotes in a string, you have to mask it:

You can mask either by `string mystring = @"<span class=""icon phone"">m</span>";` or by masking the quotes directly with a backslash `(\)` `string mystring = "<span class=\"icon phone\">m</span>";`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply

```
String html = "<span class=\"icon phone\">m</span>"
```

Or you can use a String literal:

```
String html = @"<span class=""icon phone"">m</span>"
```

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  string str="<span class=\"icon phone\">m</span>";
```