# How do I insert a string containing a single-quote character?

Tags: sql-server-2008, insert

I have a problem with this `insert` query in SQL Server 2008

```
insert into Book values('B0000001I002','C# 3.0: A Beginner's Guide')
```

How do I make SQL ignore the single-quote in `C# 3.0: A Beginner's Guide`?

Comment: Which language? Or is directly SQL Server?

Answer (score 7):

This question was [asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1586560/how-do-i-escape-a-single-quote-in-sqlserver) and the answer is to escape the `'` by doubling it:

```
INSERT INTO Book VALUES('B0000001I002','C# 3.0: A Beginner''s Guide')
```

Comment: Thanks. Sorry about duplicate question but I searched it at google and find nothing

Answer (score 0):

you can do it using escape sequence

Check:

[Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
insert into Book values('B0000001I002','C# 3.0: A Beginner\'s Guide')
```

Comment: Whoever gave downvote, please check the answered time, I didn't copy paste from another, I give the answer first and who earn 5 votes, he give the answer4 minutes later!