# How do I include quotation marks in a string?

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I have string variables that need to contain quotation marks. Unsurprisingly enough, putting "" inside `"a string like this"` will end the string then create a new one.

For example:

```
writer.WriteLine("{"); //first line is ok
writer.WriteLine("  "profiles": {  "); 
// the word "profiles" not treated as just another part of the string
// but I need to write this text, quotes and all:
//     "profiles": {
```

How can I put quotation marks inside a string?

Comment: They're generally known as 'double quotes' or 'quotation marks'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, can I escape a double quote in a literal string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-literal-string)

Comment: @alexisdm Related but not a duplicate, since that's a different problem faced in literal strings where you can't just `@"do \"this\""` (there's no escaping in literal strings, so you can't escape the quotation marks to prevent them from ending the string!)

Comment: @alexisdm The solution to that question (`@"use ""double"" quotation marks"`, expressed in the top two answers) doesn't work for non-literal strings. Reading only the titles, one could be forgiven thinking they're duplicates, but reading the questions themselves should clarify the matter, and the answers to each are not relevant to the other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to escape them.

```
writer.WriteLine("  \"profiles\": {  ");
```

Comment: Hmm...thank you. But also ":" is now getting that...something.

Comment: Mousing over "profiles" : Only assignment, call, increment, (few other) and new object expressions can be used as statement.

On ":" : Invalid expression term ".

On "{" : ; expected.

Comment: @Valters I suspect you didn't use the above code as keyboardP wrote it.

Comment: Oh Dear, I just noticed, that I missed one ". Haha, silly me.

Comment: This would work too: `writer.WriteLine(@"  ""profiles"": {  ");`

Comment: Indeed. OP you can read more about the `@` symbol [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx)

Comment: Ouch, and now...if I have something like this: `"username": "VARIABLEUSER",` and I want only VARIABLEUSER spot being treathed as variable, but having "" on both sides, when on written file?

Comment: If you wanted quotes surrounding the value of the variable, you could do something like this: `"\"username\": " + "\"" + VARIABLEUSER + "\", "` So if `VARIABLEUSER` was, say, "Joe", then you would see this in the output: `"username": "Joe",` and whatever follows after the comma.