# regex lookbehind followed by lookahead

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds

INPUT:
garbage="stff",start1="allshortsofCharactersExceptDoubleQuotes",start2="*&^%$blahblah"

DESIRED RESULT:
allshortsofCharactersExceptDoubleQuotes

*&^%$blahblah

Using c# .NET:

```
string myRegExString = @"(?<=start[0-9].).*(?="")"
```

Yeilds:
allshortsofCharactersExceptDoubleQuotes",start2="*&^%$blahblah

Through testing I know that if I replaced .* with a set that had all the characters except double quotes I would get the desired result but that is a lot of work and I will get that wrong.  Also using (?!"") or (?!="") before .* does not work either.

So how do I get the lookahead to stop on the first double quote it finds?

Correct Answers (as far as I tested) from the responses:

```
(?<=start\d+="")[^""]*(?="")
```

OR

```
(?<=start\d+="")[^""]+(?="")
```

OR this works too but is not quite what was asked for.

```
(?<=start\d+="")[^""]*
```

Thanks.  I was so wrapped up in the lookahead aspect of this item.

Answer (score 1):

You should use lazy quantifier `.*?` which would match as less as possible..In your case `.*` would match as much as possible and hence it would capture till last `"`

```
(?<=start\d+="").*?(?="")
```

You could get a list of such of values using this code

```
List<string> output=Regex.Matches(input,regex)
                         .Cast<Match>()
                         .Select(x=>x.Value)
                         .ToList();
```

Comment: thanks.  will try the Linq another time.  did not test this out

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your regular expression is that .* is matching too much text. You can make your regular expression lazy by adding a question mark after the star like '.*?' Or you can change it to match every thing except double quoutes with: `'[^"]*'` which is what I would choose in this case. The following should work. Not tested

```
string myRegExString = @"(?<=start[0-9].)[^""]*(?="")"
```

The other solution I suggests is:

```
string myRegExString = @"(?<=start[0-9].).*?(?="")"
```

Comment: the first is not going to match anything since you are missing `"`..in second your result would include 1st `"`

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal The double quote is escaped by an extra double quote in string lterals

Comment: Thanks!  Both of those worked.  I got so wrapped up in the lookahead I could not see the obvious :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
@"(?<=start\d="")[^""]+(?="")"
```

the result is the whole pattern.

Comment: @Anirudh: yes and no, because this checks there's a double quote after. Imagine with this string:`abcd start2="abcd`, what should i do?

Comment: thanks.  Yes the (?="") is redundant but is what I asked for and demonstrates that a lookahead can be used if required.