# How to have a verbatim string literal inside a verbatim string literal?

Tags: c#, string, string-literals, verbatim-string

How can I stores something like the following string in C#:

```
string mystring = @"CMD.AddParameters("@Pkey", SqlDbType.Int, Pkey.ToString());";
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In C#, can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Not really a duplicate (of that particular question) since the code in this question is a regular string literal, not a verbatim literal (`@""`).

Comment: @cdhowie OP wants to put that literal into a verbatim string literal, though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string mystring = "CMD.AddParameters(\"@Pkey\", SqlDbType.Int, Pkey.ToString());";
```

or

```
string mystring = @"CMD.AddParameters(""@Pkey"", SqlDbType.Int, Pkey.ToString());";
```

Answer (score 2):

- escape using the backslash:
  `"CMD.AddParameters(\"@Pkey\", SqlDbType.Int, Pkey.ToString());"`
- use unicode literals:
  `"CMD.AddParameters(\u0022@Pkey\u0022, SqlDbType.Int, Pkey.ToString());"`

fwiw, here is a link to [msdn on C# verbatim strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms228362.aspx).