# Escape single quote in a SQL query string in C#

Tags: c#, sql, escaping

Just assume that I have no control of creating the query string, for example,

```
select * from customer where name='Joe's construction'
```

Also, there isn't any control of executing the query, for example, pass this to a [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) API to execute on a database.

I need to escape the query as

```
 select * from customer where name='Joe\'s construction'
```

So I need to write a function like this:

```
 string escape(string sql)
```

The function pass the origin query and return the escaped string, so it can use the function like this:

```
 string s = "select * from customer where name='Joe's construction'";
 string es = escape(s);
 // 'es' should equals "select * from customer where name='Joe\'s construction'"
```

How can I make this function escape work?

Again, I have *no* control of creating that SQL query. I am *only* able to get the query string as a whole piece. And I am not using it to execute on any database; I just need to escape it and pass to an API.

Comment: Sigh. If you're not able to use parameterized queries, you're in trouble. "Escaping" is never gonna get it done.

Comment: And I know you're not executing this query directly, but _someone_ will, and they're doing it **very** wrong.

Comment: Is the SQL not already properly escaped for single quotes? I ask because `"... where name='Joe's construction'"` is invalid and should be `"... where name='Joe''s construction'"`.

Comment: escape the string  as name='Joe''s construction' is fine for me too, that won't make the question easier i think

Comment: This is in the top 2 for a search engine hit for "C# escape single quotes"... What is the canonical question for escaping string in C#? It definitely exists. Candidate: *[Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal/1928943#1928943)* (as an answer covers the most common cases and the external reference the rest).

Comment: However, is *this* question about escaping in C# or in SQL (or both at the same time)?

Answer (score 1):

Replace all single quotes with escaped quotes, and then remove the first and last slash. This will escape all inner single quotes.

```
string sql = "select * from customer where name = 'Joe's construction'";
sql = sql.Replace(@"'", @"\'");
sql = sql.Remove(sql.LastIndexOf(@"\"), 1).Remove(sql.IndexOf(@"\"), 1);
```

Comment: This won't work with more than one literal string in the query.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to resolve...

Just write a single quote twice in your query and it will be accepted by the SQL server...

You cannot escape a single quote with a backslash—you need another single quote:

```
select * from customer where name = 'Joe''s construction'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done something like this, and I didn't get any exception. This is probably a solution, but keep it mind the [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issue that may come with it.

```
name.Replace("'", $"{(char)39}");
```

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: This is old now, but I'm here because I have (had) another answer on this question that was upvoted today. Looking back, I took the question a little too much at face value and don't recommend my original answer.*

---

> I have no control of creating the query string... Also, there isn't any control of executing the query, for example, pass this to a REST API to execute on a database.

Then I would beg off the assignment. I'm absolutely serious.

What you are asked to do is write software that you KNOW, with 100% certainly, will contain a **serious SQL injection flaw.** I have ethical issues being part of that.

The **ONLY** correct way to handle data like this is via **parameterized queries**. Parameterized queries do NOT sanitize or escape data. It's now how they work. Instead, they **isolate** query date from the SQL command string. At no point is the data ever substituted back into the query. In this way, you are perfectly protected from SQL injection. Anything else is only a matter of time until some unicode character or new feature opens up a serious attack route.