# How to escape double quotation marks in a formula

Tags: c#, excel

I want to write this code in C#:

```
//
excelCellrange = excelSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1");
excelCellrange.Formula = "=IF(A1="Harm",100)";

//Copy formula to other cells:
excelCellrange = excelSheet.get_Range("B2", B10);
excelCellrange.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormulas);
```

But I cant write `"Harm"` in "". How to solve this?

Comment: Try: `excelCellrange.Formula = "=IF(A1=\"Harm\",100)";
`

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/in-c-can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape your quotation marks like this:

```
excelCellrange.Formula = "=IF(A1=\"Harm\",100)";
```

You can find a good list of escape sequences here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-character-escape-sequences-are-available.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the quotes by preceding them with a `\` so the line would become
    `excelCellrange.Formula = "=IF(A1=\"Harm\",100)";`