# Escape double quotes in a C# string

Tags: c#, string, escaping, double-quotes

I'm trying to escape `\` and `"` in my string like this:

```
text.Replace("\\", "\\\\").Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

But the result for `text`,

```
arash "moeen"
```

turns out as

```
arash \\\"moeen\\\"
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What is `text` at start? You are replacing \ with \\ and `"` with `\"`.

Comment: Why do you need to escape them?

Comment: text = arash "moeen"

Comment: So you want your resulting text to turn out as: `arash \"moeen\"`?

Comment: as they tend to break my json string when I parse it.

Comment: @Marlon yes, exactly that what I want my result to be.

Comment: @arashmoeen have you considered using any well known json serializer? I understand in some cases you may want light weight solution, and hence a simple hackish (not necessarily bad) solution.. but only if you are sure you want your own solution.

Comment: @VikasGupta that's true, I should be considering that as a correct solution anyway. I assume c# comes with a built in json serializer.

Comment: @arashmoeen .Net (not C#) does have couple built in that I know of.. `JavaScriptSerializer` and `DataContractJsonSerializer`. Given the original question has been posed as a string manipulation question, I am not sure how exactly you could utilize these classes.. but there they are for you reference.. Some other external libraries like Json.Net *may* have helper functions, which could potentially help with such escaping rather than full fledged serialization, should you need only escaping.

Comment: The canonical is *[Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/)*. This was the third hit in a search engine result and the second in another (probably because the title contains "C#" which the canonical questions don't).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `@` for verbatim literal strings.

```
text.Replace(@"this", @"that");
```

Example:

```
text.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"""", @"\""");
```

Comment: And use double quote for quotes: i.e. to get `a "b"` you type `@"a ""b"""`.

Comment: so for escaping " how should it be? .replace(@"\"", @"\\\"") ??

Comment: It should be text.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"""", @"\""")

Comment: yea thanks but now after replacing it becomes arash \\\"moeen\\\" then after I parse it, it becomes arash \"moeen\" in my textarea

Comment: @arashmoeen Well, then I've got no idea what you want or what you're dealing with.

Comment: sorry @B.K. , as it turns out I had a typo, now it's working as it should be. thanks again

Answer (score 3):

What is your assignment's code?

It should be

```
var text = @"arash ""moeen""";
```

Comment: Use this if it's a multiline string

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, first of all, `text = arash "moeen"`  is not a valid regular string literal. I assume your string like;

```
string s = "text = arash \"moeen\"";
```

which is printed as

```
text = arash "moeen" // I think this is your original string.
```

Since you `arash \"moeen\"` as a result, you just need to replace your `"` with `\"` in your string like;

```
string s = "text = arash \"moeen\"";
s = s.Replace("\"", "\\\"");
```

So your result will be `arash \"moeen\"`

More information: [Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

If this is a JSON string, my answer will be invalid :-p

Comment: yea it'll be as part of a JSON string, it'll end up arash \"moeen\" in my textview after I parse it

Answer (score 2):

```
string text = @"arash ""moeen""";
MessageBox.Show(text.Replace(@"\", @"\\").Replace(@"""", @"\"""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have string like this

```
string test = "He said to me, \"Hello World\". How are you?";
```

The string has not changed in either case - there is a single escaped " in it.
This is just a way to tell C# that the character is part of the string and not a string terminator.

Answer (score -2):

When you want `arash \"moeen\"` from `arash "moeen"`, do `text.Replace(", \");`.

Comment: When u do string text = "arash "moeen"" and then text.Replace(",\");

Comment: @Sybren that won't even compile. There is no overload of string.Replace that takes one argument of type string.