# appending a character with double quotes using stringbuilder in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, stringbuilder

Hi I want to append the line

> <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

to a text file but I am stuck at the "C#" , "WebForm1.aspx.cs" and "WebApplication1.WebForm1" part my code is as below

```
 public string HeaderContent1()
 {
     var sb = new StringBuilder();
     sb.Append("<%@ Page Language=");
     sb.Append("c#");// prints only c#
     sb.Append("AutoEventWireup=");
     sb.Append("true");
     sb.Append("CodeBehind=");
     sb.Append("WebForm1.aspx.cs");// prints only WebForm1.aspx.cs I want with double quotes
     sb.Append("WebApplication1.WebForm1");// prints only WebApplication1.WebForm1 I want with double quotes
     sb.Append("%>");

     sb.AppendLine();
     sb.Append("<html>");
     sb.AppendLine();// which is equal to Append(Environment.NewLine);
     sb.Append("<head>");
     sb.AppendLine();
     sb.Append("<h1>New File header</h1>");
     sb.AppendLine(); // which is equal to Append(Environment.NewLine);
     sb.Append("</head>");
     sb.AppendLine();
     sb.Append("<body>");
     sb.AppendLine(); // which is equal to Append(Environment.NewLine);
     sb.Append("<h2> New File Body</h2>");
     sb.AppendLine();

     sb.Append("</body>");
     sb.AppendLine();

     sb.Append("</html>");
     sb.AppendLine();
}
```

Comment: i want to append <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Answer (score 5):

You have a couple options when trying to use a quote *inside* a quoted string.

You can escape the quotations:

```
sb.Append("\"WebForm1.aspx.cs\"");
```

Or use a verbatim symbol:

```
sb.Append(@"""WebForm1.aspx.cs""");
```

You could eliminate the `StringBuilder` altogether:

```
var page = "<%@ Page Language=\"C#\" AutoEventWireup=\"true\" CodeBehind=\"WebForm1.aspx.cs\" Inherits=\"WebApplication1.WebForm1\" %><html>\r\n<head>\r\n<h1>New File header</h1>\r\n</head>\r\n<body>\r\n<h2> New File Body</h2>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `@` before the string and add `""` where you want to print `"` for example

```
sb.Append(@"""c#""");
```

will print `"c#"`. Here's the complete modified code

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"<%@ Page Language=");
sb.Append(@"""c#""");
sb.Append(" AutoEventWireup=");
sb.Append(@"""true""");
sb.Append(" CodeBehind=");
sb.Append(@"""WebForm1.aspx.cs""");
sb.Append(" Inherits=");
sb.Append(@"""WebApplication1.WebForm1""");
sb.Append("%>");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("<html>");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("<head>");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("<h1>New File header</h1>");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("</head>");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("<body>");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("<h2> New File Body</h2>");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("</body>");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append("</html>");
sb.AppendLine();
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eEGgUJ