# How can i add <div class="thumbWrapper"> as string?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this line:

```
index = html.IndexOf("<div class="thumbWrapper">");
```

I need to use escape somehow so  will be a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape the `"` as `\"`:

```
int index = html.IndexOf("<div class=\"thumbWrapper\">");
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [verbatim strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1928909/2157640): `@"<div class=""thumbWrapper"">"`