# SQL Connection String C# ASP NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

So I'm working on making a submit content page that will store the users input into a database, here is the code I have so far:

```
protected void submitData_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string userId = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        int categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(categories.SelectedValue);
        if (categoryId > 0 && content.Text != "" && description.Text != "")
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="C: \Users\Will\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\inshort\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF";Integrated Security=True"))
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO aspnet_newscontent (author, username, date, category, content, description) VALUES (@author, @username, @date, @category, @content, @description)");
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@author", nameInput.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", userId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Today);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", categoryId);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@content", content.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", description.Text);
                connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            errorLabel.Text = "Please fill in the required fields.";
        }
    }
```

However, I am getting an error saying that the connection string contains an invalid character "\", which makes sense but whenever I go to my database's properties and look at the Connection String property, that is what it says.
I am using Microsoft Sql Server Express to have the database locally hosted if that changes anything. Anyone know how to format these connection strings?

Comment: Escape the double quotes in the string, for verbatim string, use double *double* quotes like `@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""C: \Users\Will\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\inshort\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF"";Integrated Security=True"` -- VOTING TO CLOSE AS A TYPO

Comment: Well it is possible that this post would help people with similar problems learn how to properly use escape characters.

Comment: There are plenty of posts on SO for that as well, this question could be considered a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the syntax highlighting.  You're trying to put un-escaped double-quotes in a string, which clearly confuses the parser because it thinks your string is terminating earlier and just full of syntax errors after it.

To escape quotes in a verbatim string literal (one prepended with an `@`), you need to "double"-double quote them.  Like this:

```
@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=""C:\Users\Will\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\inshort\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF"";Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: This did the trick, I will accept this answer as soon as it lets me.

Comment: You really should use this format: Data Source=DataBaseServerName;Initial Catalog=SQLDatabaseName

Comment: @Chuck: Would that work with LocalDB at all?  Changing the entire SQL infrastructure just to make the connection string look cleaner doesn't seem like a good use of effort.

Answer (score 2):

You must escape certain characters in a C# string.  If you take away the "literal" string character (@), it will look like this:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"C:\\Users\\Will\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2015\\WebSites\\inshort\\App_Data\\ASPNETDB.MDF\";Integrated Security=True"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, you need to escape the special characters in your connection string.

In practice, with asp.net many developers simply place the connection string in their `web.config` and then access it later this way if it ever changes you only have to change it in one place:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C: \Users\Will\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\inshort\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF;Integrated Security=True/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

And then access it using:

```
private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Comment: You're missing closing double quotes in your config.