# C# verbatim quote escaping String vs ToString()

Tags: c#

I try to create a unit test,

I have a code that produces the following string:

```
{<a class="btn btn-default" href="Page1">1</a><a class="btn btn-default btn.primary selected" href="Page2">2</a><a class="btn btn-default" href="Page3">3</a>}
```

(this is what visual studio debugger shows me.)

I try to compare it with const

```
  const string str = @"{<a class=""btn btn-default"" href=""Page1"">1</a>"
                           + @"<a class=""btn btn-default btn-primary selected"" href=""Page2"">2</a>"
                           + @"<a class=""btn btn-default"" href=""Page3"">3</a>}";
```

but I get (as I see in the debugger)

```
"{<a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"Page1\">1</a><a class=\"btn btn-default btn-primary selected\" href=\"Page2\">2</a><a class=\"btn btn-default\" href=\"Page3\">3</a>}"
```

how do I remove the extra slashes?

edit the problem was i had btn.default instead of btn-default

Comment: Did you try printing it? They appear only at the debugger

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Answer (score 7):

In the debugger click on the magnifying glass icon, and you will get the string without backslash.

In real there is no back slash, it is just a way of showing value in the debugger.

[image]

That is how it should appear:

[image]

Comment: In other words, the verbatim literal only applies in code.  The debugger will display it as a regular string and not use the verbatim syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The slashes appear only on the debugger. If you try printing this string or using it elsewhere, you'll see they're not there

You see them in the debugger because this is how a string is composed in order for the `\` character to appear. The `@` verbatim is just a syntactic sugar that abstracts it for you.

Answer (score -1):

OK.
Seems this is a weird Visual studio behaviour

the slashes are added only when you hover a string.

when I hover a const string
[image: when I hover a const string]

when I hover StringBuilder
[image: when I hover StringBuilder]

Comment: the  StringBuilder.ToString() and the const string I have are equal.
I excepted them to have same display in the debugger. the fact they don't is weird and confusing.

Comment: No, it ain't. They're different classes. When using a StringBuilder, it means I'm constructing (possibly dinamically) a string. I probably want to see the string the way it will be displayed. But, well, that's a matter of opinion, really :)