# How do I maintain multiple quotes quoted in a string in c#

Tags: c#, string, concatenation, quote, verbatim-string

So I have this piece of text that I need to be on a string so I can later add to a text file and should be like this string

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
<requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506" />
</startup>
```

I've tried to verbate it like

```
@"""<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506" />
    </startup>"""
```

and also tried to work with concatenatio but I can't see to figure out how to include every quote to be on that string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Comment: Use the quote escape sequence. \"

Comment: `@"\""` is the two characters \"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handy tool here 
http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

Input the string and it will escape it for you.

```
"<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=\"true\">\r\n    <supportedRuntime version=\"v4.0\" sku=\".NETFramework,Version=v4.0\"/>\r\n    <requiredRuntime version=\"v4.0.20506\" />\r\n  </startup>"
```

Answer (score 4):

Double quotes escape a single quote within `@""`:

```
string Text = @"<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=""true"">
    <supportedRuntime version=""v4.0"" sku="".NETFramework,Version=v4.0""/>
    <requiredRuntime version=""v4.0.20506"" />
  </startup>";
```

Comment: I've tried to do it as you mentioned but didnt worked for me.
Instead I did as follows:
"<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=\"true\">\r\n<supportedRuntime version=\"v4.0\" sku=\".NETFramework,Version=v4.0\"/>\r\n<requiredRuntime version=\"v4.0.20506\" />\r\n</startup>"

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string value =
                @"<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=""true""> <supportedRuntime version=""v4.0"" sku="".NETFramework,Version=v4.0""/>
                 <requiredRuntime version=""v4.0.20506"" /></startup>";
            Console.WriteLine(value);
            Console.Read();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can preface the initial double-quote of a string with the '@' character to handle escaping it :

```
var startupTag = @"<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy=""true"">
                           <supportedRuntime version=""v4.0"" sku="".NETFramework,Version=v4.0""/>
                           <requiredRuntime version=""v4.0.20506"" />
                   </startup>";
```

You can [see a live example of this here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/20uvQK).