# How to assign a JSON value to a string variable

Tags: c#, json, string

Some value is saved in JSON format in DB and if I copy it from DB it looks like this:

```
[{"id":"FAC2SOUTHX","name":"South District MW        ","description":"South District MW                                           ","selected":true,"required":false,"sortOrder":10}]
```

Now I want to write a unit test that for its mock object I need to pass that value and the mock value is a string.  But `C#` giving error if I want to assign that value to a string variable. So I thought all I have to do is to prefix it with a `"@"` but didn't work either. 
So how can I assign that value to a string variable.

Comment: Encolse that JSON in double quotes and escape all the double quotes inside it.

Comment: Or just replace double quotes inside the JSON with single quotes, whichever is easier for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to comment all qoutes with a backslash so the string is recognized as a String
e.g.

```
string s = "My string with \" qouted \" Values";
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use duplicated double quotes like this

```
string str = @"[{""id"":""FAC2SOUTHX"",""name"":""South District MW        "",""description"":""South District MW                                           "",""selected"":true,""required"":false,""sortOrder"":10}]";
```

Have a look at this question [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Answer (score 1):

first you need to escape your string. before each inner quotes you have to use a backslash so " becomes \".

Then you could simply use something like Newtonsoft.Json to cast that string into a proper object and check the value that way.

The code is very simple you can use something like :

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(your_string);
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `@` and use `\` to escape the `"`

```
string someJson = "[{\"id\":\"FAC2SOUTHX\",\"name\":\"South District MW        \",\"description\":\"South District MW                                           \",\"selected\":true,\"required\":false,\"sortOrder\":10}]"
```