# C#: I get CS1002 and CS1525 error because of qoutes - how to avoid that?

Tags: c#

I have this simple code:

```
var q = "this is a test";
return q.Length;
```

Just that sometimes I need to be able to insert string that contains double quotes and this yields those errors

```
var q = "this is "not" a test";
```

How can I avoid that without manually escaping chars? I need something like python has its triple quotes when you can include anything

```
q  = '''I can include 'everything' in here as long it's not triple quotes'''
```

Comment: @Amy this is not a duplicate of the post you mentioned. It's the opposite.

Comment: Then pick your possible duplicate.  Another possible dupe:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can state a `@` at the beginning of your string:

```
var q = @"this ""is"" how you do it.";
```

Comment: Or to avoid double quoting, you can `escape` characters inside of strings as such: `var q = "this \"is\" how you do it` which will `Console.Write()` as `this is how you do it`.

Comment: So that's what the @ stands for :) Thank you!