# Why is the @ sign used in things like page redirects?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone explain why people use the @ sign in things like page redirections?

For example;

> response.redirect(@"mypage.aspx");

Seems to work exactly the same as;

> response.redirect("mypage.aspx");

I would like to know the purpose of the @ sign.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: Verbatim strings give you ability to write multiline strings as is, no need for it in this string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I escape a double quote in a verbatim string literal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1928909/can-i-escape-a-double-quote-in-a-verbatim-string-literal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@` before the string indicates the string is a verbatim string:
So if you are redirecting to a page that is not on the current location as the view, you could say `response.redirect(@"path\mypage.aspx")`. Without the `@`, you have to say `response.redirect("path\\mypage.aspx")`

For your code, you do not need it since the page you are redirecting to is on the same location.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Comment: Perfect explanation and that explains it clearly. +1 for providing the link to the reference material. I shall read more into this to fully understand it. Thanks, Frank!