# Regex look behind until whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

```
 string corrected = Regex.Replace(input, @">(?<=disposition)", "R");
```

Is it possible to replace ">" only in cases that it is preceded by "disposition" without any whitespaces between it?

I'm asking because I have pseudo XML with attributes like `disposition="4<^12^13>>^^<^14,5<^20"` in many elements. I load it as one big string, do various fixes and only then I parse it to XML.

I can't think of many sollutions... In case Regex can't do what I'm asking, I can think only of separating that big string by whitespaces and fix every attribute individually then, but I'm afrad that  will create a lot of load.

Comment: You mean `Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\bdisposition=""[^""]*)>", "R")`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That works, thank you very much. So do I understand correctly that in Regex whitespaces makes word boundary, so moving to start of word makes my request possible? Rn I don't even know what ```[^""]``` does... but it works and I don't really plan to study Regex anytime soon. 

Thanks for working solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```cs
Regex.Replace(text, @"(?<=\bdisposition=""[^""]*)>", "R")
```

Here, the regex is `(?<=\bdisposition="[^"]*)>`, the [`"` is doubled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1928909/3832970) only because the string literal is the verbatim string literal here.

*Details*:

- `(?<=\bdisposition="[^"]*)` - a positive lookbehind (`(?<=...)`) that requires, immediately to the left of the current location):

  - `\b` - word boundary
  - `disposition="` -  a literal text
  - `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than `"` char
- `>` - a `>` char.